# Memory Exception while running a container which executes a Python script but I didn't see any memory leakage

Tags: python, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, containers

Python script which just downloads 5k files from a SFTP location and read the file and load the data to the database
Execution step will look like this
SFTP Connection
Get list of files to process
Iterate one by one
a. Download one file
b. Read file
c. Load data to database
d. Delete the file
(Repeat step 3 for all the files)

In the code level, I don't see any memory leakage. But my container exit with a memory error.
If i run on my local machine and checks the container stats, i see it asks for 70mb for processing single file (to store temp data, etc). When it process file 2, its askng for another 70mb approximately without releasing the previous in-active memory.

I read a little bit about Python GC, looks like, unlike many other languages, Python GC  will not return the memory to the OS instead it will return to it's internal memory allocator. Any thoughts on how to overcome this problem

```
def batch_load(self):
    logging.info("SFTP to DB")
    logging.info("SFTP Operations")
    files = self.sftp_src_strategy.list_contents()
    for file in files:
        exec_date = file.split('.')[0][-8:]
        execution_date = f'{str(exec_date[:4])}-{str(exec_date[4:6])}-{str(exec_date[6:8])}'
        header_row, data = self.sftp_src_strategy.download_data(execution_date, exec_date, file)
        logging.info("Sftp Download Success + Data extracted from file")
        logging.info("DB Operations")
        self.db_des_strategy.load_data(execution_date, header_row, data)
        logging.info("Data moved to db from SFTP file successfully")
```

Comment: post the code please

Comment: Python does not return the memory to the operating system but it does free it in the local heap. Now its available for allocations by python. Assuming you really did free the memory (not just close the file but delete any objects still referencing the data), the next read should just use the same memory again. If you use something like numpy that does a large single object allocation, there may be issues where freed memory isn't big enough and more needs to be allocated.

Comment: @tdelaney In that case, do you want me to do `del my_var`

Comment: Yes. I assume `header_row, data` is where your 70 meg is. Since the first run's data in those variables isn't deleted until `self.sftp_src_strategy.download_data` overwrites it, you've got both the old and the new dataset in memory at the same time. Either `del` everything at the end of each `for` loop, or (better IMHO) put that stuff that is in the `for` into a different function. I'll write up an answer.

Comment: @tdelaney I tried both actually. I moved the processing code which is inside the for loop to a separate function. That didn't help. I have also tried del my_var + gc.collect(). That doesn't help either

Comment: The quick solution is to go back to your separate function, but use `multiprocessing` to put it in a `Process` that only handles 1 file. Or even just write a new .py file that does that bit of work and takes parameters on the command line. Then use the `subprocess` module to run it.

Comment: I'll skip my first suggestion because you already tried it.

Comment: The `gc` and `inspect` modules can help figure out where the memory is. You could break into the progam after its first procesing step and look for any memory still in use.